# Failed-bq-insert-elements-total metric for missing data in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

We are using Dataflow where PubSub consumes two types of messages and should connect the two if they match and output them into BigQuery.
We have investigated the problem where BQ doesn't have these coupled records after the job is complete.
And now we are looking to create alerts for this in order to fix the problem immediately rather than later.

We're looking at what's already implemented by us and what's in Metrics Explorer.

Inside Metrics Explorer, I found this alert:

`Failed-bq-insert-elements-total`

It mentions that that metric is "user defined dataflow metric" so I take it, it needs to be refined in some way that's more specific to the problem that I'm trying to alert on?

I was wondering if anyone else has utilised this metric before?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you writing to BigQuery? Are you using the pattern at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309470?

Comment: can you share more details about how you're writing to BQ? which SDK are you using (Python/Java)?